# which is better for writing a sensitive log file from C++, write() on a file descriptor or fprintf() on a FILE?

Tags: c++, file-io

My understanding is that `write()` is a system call, which is extremely slow.  (It's almost like a kind of inter-process communication.)  Anything that works with `FILE` is buffered and only does a system call every 512 bytes or what have you.  So speed-wise `FILE` should be much faster.

But if you have a log message followed by something that causes a coredump, there is no mechanism I know of whereby the OS could go dig up the `FILE`'s buffer and write it do disk.  So, you could easily be missing the last 5-10 lines of your log file.  For software like finance software, where bugs can literally cost billions and you don't want to have any bug twice, and therefore need great logging, that would be bad.

At least that was the stance 25 years ago.  I'm curious whether things have changed these days?  For instance is there a mechanism whereby OS's tell standard C libraries to flush output buffers even after a SEGV or something?  If so then `FILE` suddenly looks a lot better: speed without the reliability.  Plauger in his 1992 book on the Standard C Library mentioned that in theory write() could also be a buffered function of some sort instead of a system call.

Part of the question is: are there any compilation options on Windows or Linux that affects this tradeoff?  Not just `-O2`, say, but options that actually affect buffer flushing upon core dump?

This isn't a theoretical question into what's allowed, but rather a practical question about today's and upcoming Linux and Windows.  While I know the various standards in question will promise some or another level of reliability or performance, often these are weakened to the point of uselessness as they're trying to cover rare situations like a C interpreter, or code running on an 80s Cray, or something.  Also, while I can (and am) testing this myself, my question is a bit broader than just what today's software gives me with default compilation options.

Comment: What is your average log line size? If it's larger than (or close to) `BUFSIZ` then it may not matter which you use. And if ensuring that the log lines are written is critical, you would want to flush buffers after each line anyway. In that case it would be better to ensure that the underlying storage for log files is low-latency (even if throughput is not high).

Comment: Use `syslog()` and offload the problem to another process.

Comment: > "And if ensuring that the log lines are written is critical, you would want to flush buffers after each line anyway."  With write() I'm sure the OS will always flush your changes even if you coredump immediately.  Am I naive?  Just talking Linux and Windows btw.

Comment: flush() tells the libc to do a write(). That only transferes the data to the kernel. It's still cached there. Once in kernel a crash of the app is harmless though but a kernel crash will still loose the data. If the log is critical you also have to fsync() or open the file with O_SYNC.

Comment: To be clear the worry is the app crash, not a kernel crash.

Answer (score 1):

Things has not changed. CRT and OS kernel still separate kingdoms. And there are no such options that would affect this. You have to take care yourself with special means. Hint:  look into memory mapped files.

Comment: I have.  Torvalds has commented that memmap files actually can be slower since due to page faults, MMU, TLB etc. can be quite slow.  My suspicion is that there surely are tuning params that should make it no slower than fwrite(), but not sure it'd be faster.  I'll do some testing...
 http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0004.0/0728.html

Comment: Never mmap a file to write it. First you have to fallocate the file large enough. Then when you write to the memory the kernel has to read in the page from the file. Which might segfault on read error. Next the write to memory happens and some random time later the page gets flushed back to disk. You have to mysnc() it to force a write. And then there is no way to know if that succeeded. mysnc() doesn't return EIO on write error according to specs. So you will never know if stuff actually got written or lost.

Comment: I'll consider your cautions Goswin but would make the following points.  You only have to size the file (I think I've used ftruncate() despite the name, maybe I forget) big enough for one mapping.  Should you use up that piece, THEN ftruncate more storage.  My understanding is that disk sectors aren't allocated: you don't lose 4GB capacity when ftruncate()'ingto 4GB, only when you actually write to it.  Since the file system knows there's no actual data there, the OS will too and won't have to read anything.  You don't have to msync() as the OS will do that as soon as it gets the spare cycles.